# Is it acceptable to provide a C++ Singleton class library but provide the instance() method outside of the library

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have a class library called SingletonDemo, but I've elected to provide the static access method SingletonDemo::GetInstance() outside of the library, so when I build code for production, I want one version of Getinstance(), and when I build for unit tests, i want another version.

Comment: Why don't use conditional compiles for that (i.e. #ifdef)?

Comment: Modifying code heavily for testing purpose, comes with the risk of testing something different from production.

Comment: Why would you want two different versions of `Getinstance`? And what could be the difference between them? Typically getter functions are trivial. You aren't implementing some sort of meyers singleton by any chance?

Comment: it is a meyers singleton. yup!

Answer (score 0):

Dont you wonna use a precompiler directive for that??
seems a little more maintainable and readable...

```
#ifdef unit_test
    //unit test implementation
#else
    // normal implementation...
#endif
```

so you can switch between the implementations automatically.

But you may consider not doing that... you run into diverting behavior from your tested code to the release.

Comment: one can imagine that I'm testing a lot of software and for the unit test I'm creating an instance of SingletonDemo that is a lot different to the one in the unit test. one might imagine the instance of SingletonDemo to be a mock.

So maybe I might have SingletonDemo as an abstract class, both ProductionDemo and UnitTestDemo are derived from Singleton Demo.

I'm searching for an answer to whether my SingletonDemo sitting in a library but my SingletonDemo::GetInstance() implementation outside of the library is acceptable.

Comment: Conditional inclusion of any particular implementation is moved into the realm of build time rather than compile time and this avoids #ifdef in code. This helps decouple code.

Comment: from an academic point of view is, splitting the implementation is not very practical. one think comes to my mind, is to derive from the library class and simply override the function... maybe this could help or I just dont understand the problem.

Comment: There is the factory design pattern for this purpose.
[link to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: @Cactus I like your approach =)

Comment: Thanks all. I intend to make my ::GetInstance return a reference to abstract class and thus it will be picking up on @skratchi.at because in reality in my previous work I've done exactly that. This current piece of work is a refactor in readiness for testing. cheers.